# How to mock a specific object returned as a response to function call?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have an implementation where I want to mock a service that I have created:

```
this.device = major.get('alp").devC === 'devType';
```

This is happening in the constructor of a component. I want to mock the same in my jest test case and what I have done is:

```
jest.spyOn(major, 'get').mockImplementation(() => {
            return { devC: 'devType2' };
        });
```

I checked and can see that my code is going inside my mock and is returning the values correctly, but when I run the test cases I get devC of undefined.

I checked by putting logs in the component but then test failed at test case stating the same error above but prints correctly on the console screen where test were running with watch.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to the problem. So the issue is with the place where you put the jest.spyOn. Since I was having the method call inside the constructor, It was important to put the spy even before we create the wrapper instance or even before we take the reference of the component in shallow/mount.

If you are having any such requirement to spy on the method in the constructor call you best bet could be to put spy first thing in your test case or in beforeEach() (if you want it to be applicable on all test cases).